# How to draw a grid in canvas with random obstructions in the each square?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a web game using canvas to draw the grid and and have obstructions randomly placed on the inside of the grid. The grid will shoot a 'laser' through the grid. if the 'laser' hits an obstruction it bounces off and exits the grid at a certain angle. The game then tells the user what number the laser exited the grid at and gives the user an option to guess where the obstruction is.

My code is below. I am learning javascript and canvas but I can't get the game to work. If someone could help I would be very grateful.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var answer;
var cell = [10][10];
var history = new Array();
var cellString = [[" . "," . "," . "," / ", " \\ "]];
var guessed = 0, total;
var random = Math.random() ;
function setup() {
    draw(10,10);
    drawScreen();
}


var bafflesPlaced = function(){
    this.total = 5;
    var placed = 0;

    while(placed < total){
        this.x = random(10);
        this.y = random(10);
        var type = random(2) + 1;
        if(cell[x][y] == 0){
            cell[x][y] = type;
            placed++;
        }
    }

    var choice = document.getElementById('yourOption');
    choice.innerHTML = "";
    while(true){
        drawScreen(false);
        choice = prompt("\n1.) Shoot 2.) Guess 3.) Quit: ");
        alert(choice);
        if (choice == 1) shoot();
        if (choice == 2) guess();
        if (choice == 3) break;

    }

}

var guess = function(){
    drawScreen(true);
    var type;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    x.innerHTML = "";
    y.innerHTML = "";

    var answer = document.getElementById('yourAnswer');
    while(true){
        answer = prompt("please enter coordinate (0-9): ");
        alert(answer);
        if (x >= 0 && x <= 9) break;
    }

    while(true){
        answer = prompt("please enter coordinate (0-9): ");
        alert(answer);
        if (y >= 0 && y <= 9) break;
    }
    answer = prompt("Please enter type (/ or \\): ");
    alert(answer);
    var choice = type == '/' ? 1 : 2;
    if ($cell[x][y] == choice){
        alert("\nCorrect!");
        $cell[x][y] += 2;
        guessed++;
        alert("\nCorrect guesses: " + guessed);

        if (guessed == total){
            alert("\nYou found all of the baffles! Congratualtions!");
            //window.close();
            document.location.reload();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
    else alert("\nFalse!");

    var shoot = function(){
        choice = prompt("\nEnter entry point: 0-39");
        alert(choice);
        var choice, x = 0, y = 0, xd = 0, yd = 0;

        while(true){
            if(choice >= 0 && choice <= 39) break;
            choice = prompt("Please enter a number from 0-39: ");
            alert(choice);
        }

        var side = choice / 10;
        var where = choice % 10;
        switch (side){
            case 0:
                y = -1;
                xd = 0;
                yd = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                y = where; 
                x = 10;
                xd = -1;
                yd = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                x = 9 - where;
                y = 10;
                xd = 0;
                yd = -1;
                break;
            case 3: 
                x = -1;
                y = 9 - where;
                xd = 1;
                yd = 0; 
        }

        var t;
        while(true){
            //move one
            x += xd;
            y += yd; 
            if (x == -1 || x == 10 || y == -1 || y ==10) break;
            //baffle: /
            if (cell[x][y] == 1 || cell[x][y] == 3){
                t = xd; 
                xd = -yd;
                yd = -t;

            }
            //baffle: /
            if (cell[x][y] == 2 || cell[x][y] == 4){
                t = xd;
                xd = yd;
                yd = t;
            }

        }
        exit = draw(x,y);
        alert("Exit at" + exit + "\n");
        history.add(console.log("%d > %s", choice, exit));

    }

}

var draw = function(x,y){
    c.empty = " ";
    if (x == -1){
        if (y == -1 || y == 10) return c.empty;
        return (c(c.empty, 39-y));
    }
    if (x == 10){
        if (y == -1 || y == 10) return c.empty;
        return (c(c.empty, y + 10));
    }
    if (y == -1){
        return (c(c.empty, x));
    }
    if (x == 10){
        if (y == -1 || y == 10) return empty;
        return (c(c.empty, 29 - x));
    }
    return cellString[cell[x][y]];

}

var drawScreen = function(guess){
    //var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    //var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    c.fillStyle="grey";
    c.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.stroke(0);
    c.strokeWeight(1);
    c.lineTo(x, 0, x, canvas.height);
    c.lineTo(0, y, canvas.width, y);

    if (guess){
        for (var y = -1; y < 10; y += canvas.height / 10){
            for (var y = -1; y < 10; x += canvas.width / 10){
                /*
                c.stroke(0);
                c.strokeWeight(1);
                c.line(this.x, 0, this.x, this.height);
                c.line(0, this.y, this.width, y);*/
                if ( y == -1){
                    if (x > -1){
                        console.log(" %d", x);
                    }
                    else
                    document.print(" ");
                } else if ( x == -1){
                    if (y > -1) 
                        console.log(" %d", y);
                } else
                 draw(x,y);
            }
            return;

        }
    } else {
        for (var y = -1; y <= 10; y += canvas.height / 10){
            for (var x = -1; x <= 10; x += canvas.width / 10){
                draw(x,y);
            }
            for ( var h = y + 1; h < 100; h +=12){
                if (h < history.length()) document.print("\t" + history.get(h) + "\t");
            }
        }return;
    }
}
setup();
```

I want to have a 10X10 grid that's numbered 0-39 on the sides and have hidden obstructions placed in the grid that's not visible to the user unless they made a correct guess in that specific spot.

Comment: "I can't get the game to work" is unclear. Does the game not start? Or behave not as intended? Please be more specific

Comment: it does not start or behave as it should & I cannot seem to pinpoint where the errors are